# Quadratic optimization with quadratic constraints

Tags: r, optimization

I have the following quadratic optimization problem to solve:

$$max: x'\Sigma x$$
$$Sub: x'x = 1$$

Where,

$$\Sigma = \left[ \begin{matrix} 402.0571 & 266.6035\\
                                 266.6035 & 305.2564 \end{matrix} \right]$$

Searching the internet I found the CVXPY package that I think I can solve the problem, I did the implementation

```
library(CVXR)
Sigma = matrix(c(402.0571, 266.6035, 266.6035, 305.2564), nc = 2)
w = Variable(2)
objective = Maximize(quad_form(w, Sigma))

constraint = quad_form(w, diag(2)) == 1
problem = Problem(objective, constraints = list(constraint))
result = solve(problem)
```

however, when implementing it I get the following problem:

```
Error in construct_intermediate_chain(object, candidate_solvers, gp = gp) : 
  Problem does not follow DCP rules. However, the problem does follow DGP rules. Consider calling this 
function with gp = TRUE
```

I have no knowledge in the area of ​​convex optimization, but which PCD rule am I violating? Or is there any other mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution is any normalized eigenvector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue.  See our posts on "PCA" for (much) more.

Comment: Tanks for the @whuber tip, however, I would like to see the resolution in a computational way, because I have to solve a more complicated problem in which the technique used in PCA I think is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it is a lot easier, and does not require a computer. If you take the (vector) derivative of your quadratic form, you have that the conditions of an optimal point are:
$$ 2\Sigma{}x = 0$$
This is a homogeneous system, hence undetermined up to an scale factor: if $x$ is a solution, so is $kx$ for any $k$; but you can remove this indeterminacy using the condition $x'x = 1$.

Comment: Tanks for the @Tusell tip, I know the analytical solution, however, I have another similar problem to solve in which the analytical solution I think is not viable, so I would like to see the solution of this problem computationally.